# oracle apex classic report compute sum column colouring

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have an oracle apex classic report. I calculated sum of column credit,debit and balance using *compute sum* property of classic report. But I have to color the row which contains the sum of these columns(ie: the last row in classic report), to highlight the value. How can I color this row containing sum of columns?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by creating a bespoke report template.  Copy the current report template under a new name e.g. "My Report with Sum", and change the report to use the new template.

Now modify the template as follows:

1. Copy the HTML under "Column Template 1" to "Column Template 2".
2. Modify the HTML of "Column Template 1" by adding a special class to the `td` element to indicate that this row contains the sum e.g. `class="sum-row"`.
3. Add a condition to "Column Template 1" of type "Use based on PL/SQL expression" with an expression that will be true only for the sum row.  Suppose you set up your report so that the column ENAME contains the text "Sum" on the sum row; in that case the condition would be `:ENAME = 'Sum'`
4. Save the template changes.

Next, add some inline CSS to the page properties that sets the colours you want when the special class (e.g. `sum-row`) is present.  You may need to be quite selective to override CSS settings already applied by APEX.  For example (based on the APEX theme I happened to be in when I did this):

```
table.uReport>tbody>tr>td.sum-row {background-color: yellow}
```

You will probably need to experiment to get the CSS right for your case.

Comment: I can see the html in the region definition section, is that the code to be copied..?, but it is already there in the newly creted template since it is just a copy of original. I'm not that much good in html and css.I think I need to learn more about editing template, including html and css. Anyway thank you for the effort. I will be accepeting the answer after learning and checking it.

Comment: Implied in Tony's answer but not immediately obvious to me was that if a condition has been specified for the column 1 template and the condition for column template 1 is not met, the template for column 2 will be used (and so on if further conditions specified). If a condition isn't specified for column 1 template, that template will always be used instead of following templates. This means your conditional template(s) need to come first and your default column template needs to be last.